# Drawing a model in my second viewport using C++ openGL

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d, vector-graphics

I've run into a bit of a brick wall. I know my problem must be very basic, as all documentation I can find on this sort of stuff is a lot more complex and sort of overshoots where I seem to be having my problem.

```
    glViewport(0, 0, 250, 250);     // set first viewport
    DrawAxis2D(400, 400);           // draw axis
    glutWireCube(200);              // draw cube

    glViewport(250, 0, 250, 250);
    DrawAxis2D(400, 400);
    glutWireCube(200);
```

I have the view ports up, with the axis correctly drawing in both. I have confirmed that taking out the second DrawAxis2D() will remove the second axis, so I know I'm not getting my relative dimension confused.

Why is the second cube not being displayed?

Forgive me if I am not providing enough information. As I am just repeating the same procedure in the second view port, I believe my problem is how I'm calling the second cube, but all problems I perceive should have an effect on both view ports, not just one.

Comment: speculation: DrawAxis2D does not use Z-buffering, but glutWireCube does. Because you don't clear the Z-buffer in between calls to glutWireCube, rendering fails on the second call because Z-values still exist in the Z-buffer from the first call, in exactly the same places. Try calling glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT) after your second glViewport call

Comment: I would clear the color also ... and if any other buffer s used then it too (like alpha,stencil...)

Comment: clearing colour didn't have an effect. nor the depth buffer. But playing around (something I try to stay away from lately as I tend to tie a deeper knot then I have to begin with), I was able to find a solution. It was that I had not called glFlush(). I'm still very new to this, though, and I don't think I can truly answer my own question - I still have no idea why glFlush() would be required for the second cube, where the first cube and both axis functions drew perfectly